# How to wrap single quote around python dictionary to make it JSON?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse `JSON` from `Python`. I am able to parse `JSON` properly if I am using single quote around json string but if I remove that single quote then it doesn't works for me -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
# getting JSON string from a method which gives me like this
# so I need to wrap around this dict with single quote to deserialize the JSON
jsonStr = {"hello":"world"} 

j = json.loads(`jsonStr`) #this doesnt work either?
shell_script = j['hello']
print shell_script
```

So my question is how to wrap that JSON string around single quote so that I am able to deserialize it properly?

The error that I get -

```
$ python jsontest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsontest.py", line 7, in <module>
    j = json.loads('jsonStr')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: In your code example `jsonStr` is already an dictionary. If it was as string it would work. You cannot simply put a value inside quotation marks and make a string out of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing two different concepts here between `dumps()` and `loads()`

```
jsonStr = {"hello":"world"} 

j = json.loads(json.dumps(jsonStr)) #this should work
shell_script = j['hello']
print shell_script
```

But yes, it's redundant since `jsonStr` is already an object. If you wanted to try `loads()` you need a valid json string as input, like such:

```
jsonStr = '{"hello":"world"}'

j = json.loads(jsonStr) #this should work
shell_script = j['hello']
print shell_script
```

Answer (score 3):

`jsonStr` is a dictionary not a string. It's already "loaded".

You should be able to directly call

```
shell_script = jsonStr['hello']
print shell_script
```